# What happens if 'new' is used to instantiate an object without assigning it to variable?

Tags: c++, new-operator

Want to ask what happens if I write the following and run the program.

```
new int[5]; // without assigning it to a pointer.
```

The compilation passed.

But will there be a `5 * sizeof(int)` chunk of memory allocated?

What if it is an object?

```
new some_obj_[5]; // without assigning it to a pointer.
```

Will the constructor of `some_obj_` be invoked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
new int[5];//without assigning it to a pointer.
```

Yes, there will be a `5*sizeof(int)` chunk of memory allocated but inaccessible to you, since you didn't save the pointer. You will have a memory leak.

```
new some_obj_[5];//without assigning it to a pointer.
```

Yes, there will be `5*sizeof(some_obj_)` chunk of memory allocated but inaccessible to you, since you didn't save the pointer. The default constructor for `some_obj_` will be called 5 times. That should be trivial to verify. Depending on how `some_obj_` is coded you may have a memory leak.

Comment: +1 for the good point about the class type not leaking in certain situations

Comment: Is there a way to detect this? e.g. overload the new operator? or use smartpointer?

Comment: Well, you can detect it by looking at the code. Beyond that, you can't really overload or use some intrinsic feature of the core language to ensure the user saves the `new` pointer and prevent leaks.

Comment: @alexwang: Most compilers have a warning that will tell you that you failed to use the result of a function (I believe (but am not sure) this will also work here). Turn on this warning and fix all warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the array of objects will be dynamically allocated and in the second case the default constructor of `some_obj_` will be called. Since you don't store the pointer, you've lost any way to access the objects or `delete[]` the array, so you have a memory leak.

Comment: It's conceivable that the some_obj_ allocation doesn't leak. Unlikely, but conceivable. The int allocation will definitely leak.

Answer (score 1):

```
new int[5];//without assigning it to a pointer.
```

> But will there be a 5-sizeof(int) chunk of memory allocated?

**YES**, 5-sizeof(int) chunk of memory allocated and 5 ints are not initialized to 0

> What if it is an object?

```
new some_obj_[5];//without assigning it to a pointer.
Will the constructor of 'some_obj_' be invoked?
```

**Yes**, `sizeof(some_obj_) * 5` of memory block will be allocated and default constructor of some_obj_ will be called 5 times to initialize each element.

You are leaking these memories as you don't have pointers point to them, you can't not call `delete []` to deallocate the memory block.

See [new []](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C++%29) wiki page